# CMS with SVN browser module

Tags: svn, joomla, content-management-system, redmine

I'm looking for a **CMS** with a **SVN browser** (*Subversion*) funcionality, so I can set the url and it generate the folders and links to the files and so on.

Do you guys know if this already exists?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not often labelled a "CMS", [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) has a nice SVN browser, can cross-reference SVN revisions with issues in its issue tracker, and on the CMS side of things has modules for Wikis, News, Documentation, and Discussion Boards.

Answer (score 1):

There is something like that in [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/), it's not really a CMS but it's very well implemented.

Comment: this was precisely the example I watched and was looking for in some other module, because of the presentation issue.